# How to save data and recover it with SessionStorage?

Tags: javascript

I have this form in which I collect the data, validate it and once validated I can send it. So far so good but I also want to save it so that through the DNI you can retrieve the previous forms. And what is when the problem comes. I have created two extra functions, one to save the data and another to recover the forms. The problem is that not only the data is not saved but also when recovering only the last form is recovered without the need to put the DNI simply putting anything, that is, it is supposed that only and you can recover with the DNI and when you put a letter the entire form is already skipped and it should not be like that.

Having said all this, here is the Javascript code from where these functions come and the HTML.

```js
function reset(){
    form = document.getElementById("formu");
    arrall = formu.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i=0;i<arrall.length-3;i++){
        arrall[i].value = null;
    }
    var sel = document.getElementsByName("seleccion");
    for(var i=0;i<sel.length;i++){
        sel[i].checked=false;
        if(document.getElementById("desplegar").checked){
            var extra = document.getElementById("extra");
            extra.parentNode.removeChild(extra);
            sel.checked = false;
        }
    }
    var s =document.getElementsByName("sexual");
    for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){
        s[i].checked = false;
    }
    var txtar = document.getElementById("txtdesc");
    txtar.value = null;
}

function guardar(){
    var guardaNombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    var guardaDNI = document.getElementById('dni').value;
    var guardaemail = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var guardaedad = document.getElementById('edad').value;
    var guardasexo = document.getElementById('etsex').value;
    var guardatlf = document.getElementById('tlf').value;
    var guardaestado_civil = document.getElementById('estado_civil').value;
    var guardacookies = document.getElementById('seleccion').value;
    var guardadescripcion = document.getElementById('txtdesc').value;

    var datos = {
        nombre: guardaNombre,
        email : guardaemail,
        edad: guardaedad,
        etsex: guardasexo,
        tlf: guardatlf,
        estado_civil: guardaestado_civil,
        seleccion: guardacookies,
        txtdesc: guardadescripcion

    }

    sessionStorage.setItem(guardaDNI, datos);
}

function recupera(){
    console.log("entra");
    var guardaDNI = document.getElementById('guardaDNI').value;

    if(sessionStorage.getItem(guardaDNI)){
        console.log("Pilla el item")
        var datos = sessionStorage.getItem(guardaDNI);
        console.log(datos.modalidad);
    }else{
        window.alert("No hay datos del DNI : "+guardaDNI);
        document.getElementById('guardaDNI').value = "";
    }

}

function mostrar(){
    var options = "top = 100, left = 100, width = 800px , height= 900px";
    var new_wind;
    new_wind = window.open("","info", options);
    var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;

    var id = document.getElementById("dni");
    id.value
    var idmsg = "Tu DNI es: "+ document.getElementById("dni").value;

    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var edad = document.getElementById("edad").value;

    var asx = document.getElementsByName("sexual");
    var sx;
    for(var i=0;i<asx.length;i++){
        if(asx[i].checked ){
            sx = asx[i].value;
        }
    }

    var tlf = document.getElementById("tlf").value;


    var reg = document.getElementById("estado_civil");
    var estado_civil = reg.options[reg.selectedIndex].value;

    var select = document.getElementsByName("seleccion");
    var sel = [];
    var seleccion = "";
    for(var i=0;i<select.length-1;i++){
        if(select[i].checked){
            sel.push(select[i].value);

        }
    }

    for(var i=0;i<sel.length;i++){
        if(select[5].checked){
            if(i<sel.length){
                seleccion += sel[i]+", ";
            }else if(i==sel.length){
                seleccion +=sel[i];
            }
        }else{
            if(i<sel.length){
                seleccion += sel[i]+", ";
            }else if(i==sel.length-1){
                seleccion +=" y "+ sel[i]+".";
            }
        }

    }

    if(select.checked){
        seleccion +=" y "+ document.getElementById("extra").value+".";
    }

    var descripcion = document.getElementById("txtdesc").value;

    new_wind.document.write("<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' href='style/style.css'></head><body><div id='result'><div id='flote'>"+
        "<h1>info:</h1><br><hr>Tu nombre es: "+nombre+"<br>"+idmsg+
        "<br>Tu email es: "+email+"<br>Tu sexo es: "+sx +"<br>Tu edad: "+edad+
        "<br>Tu teléfono de contacto: "+tlf+
        "<br>Su estado civil es: "+estado_civil+"<br>Acepto las cookies: "+seleccion+
        "<br>Por último lo que escribio es lo siguiente: "+descripcion+"</div></div></body></html>"
    );
}

function recuperar(){
    var options = "top = 100, left = 100, width = 800px , height= 900px";
    var new_wind;
    new_wind = window.open("","info", options);
    var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;

    var id = document.getElementById("dni");
    id.value
    var idmsg = "Tu DNI es: "+ document.getElementById("dni").value;

    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var edad = document.getElementById("edad").value;

    var asx = document.getElementsByName("sexual");
    var sx;
    for(var i=0;i<asx.length;i++){
        if(asx[i].checked ){
            sx = asx[i].value;
        }
    }

    var tlf = document.getElementById("tlf").value;


    var reg = document.getElementById("estado_civil");
    var estado_civil = reg.options[reg.selectedIndex].value;

    var select = document.getElementsByName("seleccion");
    var sel = [];
    var seleccion = "";
    for(var i=0;i<select.length-1;i++){
        if(select[i].checked){
            sel.push(select[i].value);

        }
    }

    for(var i=0;i<sel.length;i++){
        if(select[5].checked){
            if(i<sel.length){
                seleccion += sel[i]+", ";
            }else if(i==sel.length){
                seleccion +=sel[i];
            }
        }else{
            if(i<sel.length){
                seleccion += sel[i]+", ";
            }else if(i==sel.length-1){
                seleccion +=" y "+ sel[i]+".";
            }
        }

    }

    if(select.checked){
        seleccion +=" y "+ document.getElementById("extra").value+".";
    }

    var descripcion = document.getElementById("txtdesc").value;

    new_wind.document.write("<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' href='style/style.css'></head><body><div id='result'><div id='flote'>"+
        "<h1>info:</h1><br><hr>Tu nombre es: "+nombre+"<br>"+idmsg+
        "<br>Tu email es: "+email+"<br>Tu sexo es: "+sx +"<br>Tu edad: "+edad+
        "<br>Tu teléfono de contacto: "+tlf+
        "<br>Su estado civil es: "+estado_civil+"<br>Acepto las cookies: "+seleccion+
        "<br>Por último lo que escribio es lo siguiente: "+descripcion+"</div></div></body></html>"
    );
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="flote">
      <h1>Formulario</h1>
      <hr>
      <form id="formu" action="">
        <table>

          <tr>
            <td class='labels'><label>Nombre:</label></td>
            <td><input id="nombre" type="text" name="nombre"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label name="identificacion" id="identificacion"></label>
              <label value="DNI">DNI</label>
            </td>
            <td><input id="dni" name="dni" type="text"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class='labels'><label>Email: </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class='labels'><label>Edad: </label></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="edad" id="edad"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class='labels' id="etsex">Sexo:</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="sexual" value="Mujer" id="Mujer"><label>Mujer</label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class='labels'><label></label></td>
            <td>
              <input type="radio" name="sexual" value="Hombre" id="Hombre"><label>Hombre</label>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <tr>
              <td class='labels'><label>Telefono: </label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tlf" id="tlf"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <tr>
                <td class='labels'><label>Estado </label></td>
                <td>
                  <select name="estado_civil" id="estado_civil">
                    <option value="none"> ---- Sin seleccionar ---- </option>
                  </select>
                </td>
              </tr><br>

              <tr>
                <td class='labels'><label id="seleccion">Aceptas las cookies</label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="opcion" value="si" id="si"> Si<br>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class='labels'>Y que piensas del formulario</td>
                <td><textarea name="descripcion" id="txtdesc" cols="30" rows="7" placeholder="(min 10 caracteres, max 240 caracteres)"></textarea></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class='labels'></td>
                <td>
                  <input disabled type="button" value="Enviar" id="Enviar">
                  <input type="button" value="Validar" name="validar" id="validar">
                  <input type="button" value="Borrar" name="borrar" id="borrar">
                  <input type="button" value="guardar" name="guardar" id="guardar">

                </br>

                <form id = "formrecuperar" action = "">
                Introduzca aquí el DNI para recuperar los datos: <input type = "text" id = "guardaDNI" name = "guardaDNI"></br></br>
                <input type = "button" value = "recuperar" name = "recuperar" id = "recuperar">
                </form>

                </td>
              </tr>

        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`sessionStorage.setItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) function works with *strings*, not with *objects*. That means the keys and values must be strings. One easy way to turn an object into a string is with `JSON.stringify()`, so:

`sessionStorage.setItem(guardaDNI, JSON.stringify(datos));`

After retrieving the data, you must turn it back into an object with `JSON.parse()`:

`datos = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(guardaDNI));`

Then you can populate the form with the data you retrieved:

```
document.getElementById('nombre').value = datos.nombre;
document.getElementById('email').value = datos.email ;
document.getElementById('edad').value = datos.edad;
document.getElementById('etsex').value = datos.etsex;
document.getElementById('tlf').value = datos.tlf;
document.getElementById('estado_civil').value = datos.estado_civil;
document.getElementById('seleccion').value = datos.seleccion;
document.getElementById('txtdesc').value = datos.txtdesc;
```

Or you could shorten that code:

```
['nombre', 'email', 'edad', 'etsex', 'tlf', 'estado_civil', 'seleccion', 'txtdesc'].forEach(function(key) {
  document.getElementById(key).value = datos[key];
})
```

Answer (score 1):

from what I understand you want to save your form data and recover it later for some purpose. If you want to store the data locally then you might want to store the data in localStorage whenever the form is submitted and you can also recover the form data whenever you need it from localStorage.

to store data in localstorage the format is like this (the below line saves the data in your browser's localstorage with the name formData.

```
localStorage.setItem("formData",JSON.stringify(<form data>))
```

you can get the data from localstorage using the below snippet

```
localStorage.getItem("formData")
```

the above line will get you data that is stored in formData variable.

Comment: @krishnakirit05 what I am looking for is that when you give it to save it stays saved and even if it writes other forms at the time of recovering it that I can only recover with the ID that I have saved, and that in the recover button I can only enter the ID

Comment: you forgot JSON.parse

Comment: @LawrenceCherone And where do I put that?

Comment: This saves everything under the key `formData`. OP wants to save and retrieve by DNI, which is a user-supplied value. That means you should theoretically be able to save multiple sets of settings, each under their own DNI value. So your code won't work as is.

Comment: Yes, I want to do that, but I don't know how I've been changing it for several hours and trying other things and I can't think of how to do it. @kmoser

Comment: @kmoser 's answer works if you have fewer forms, and the disadvantage of localstorage is that we have a limit of only 4MB to store in localstorage. whereas cookies as session storage have only 4Kb limit. My point here is if you have large data sets you need to have a database like Firestore or something like that.